# AWS S3 REST calls - creating signature

Tags: amazon-s3

I have 'AWS Account ID (say xxx)' and 'Access Key ID (say yyy)' with me. I am trying to issue simple REST GET call (via the POSTMAN chrome app) to list the objects in my bucket (GET BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com).
It is elementary but I am not able to find a simple way to create the signature based on this information. The s3-dg.pdf document talks of creating the signature in concept but no script/code listed that will get me there.
Can anyone help with getting from here to to the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example pseudo code on how to create a Signature (version 4)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

And here's an example Java for Signature (version 2)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

And here's how boto does it:

https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/core/auth.py